# Proof that $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}$ is unbounded. Is the following correct?

Consider arbitrary $M \in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\}$ (the case in which $M=0$ is trivial). Set $y:=\sqrt{\frac{|x|}{2}}$. Thus, for any $x$ $\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, we have that $|x|>y^2$, and so that $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}>\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^6}$. We now argue that there exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}>\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^6}>M$.

Note that $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^6}$ is monotonically increasing as $x \rightarrow 0$. Also, note that $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^6}$ is bounded above by $\frac{1}{y^2}=\frac{2}{x}$. Thus, as $x \rightarrow 0$, $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^6}$ becomes arbitrarily large (as the upper bound towards which it is monotonically increasing becomes arbitrarily large). Thus, there must exist an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}>M$, for $(x,y):=(x, \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}})$.

Comment: It's easier to just let $x=y^3.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews noted. Does my proof work as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=\frac{1}{n^3}$, $y=\frac{1}{n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Then
$$
\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}=\frac{n}{2},
$$
which $\to \infty$ when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you. Does my solutions work as well?

Comment: I'm not clear how could you realize $y=\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}$ and $x > y^2$ at the same time. So it may be wrong.

Comment: Doesn't $y=\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}} \implies x>y^2$ (since $x>\frac{x}{2}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: Right, I misread, but $x$ should be positive.  And note that $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^6} < \frac{1}{y^2}$. You cannot prove $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^6} \to \infty$ by saying $\frac{1}{y^2} \to \infty$, right?